# In Corda, can an acceptor (i.e. initiated) flow invoke subflows?

Tags: corda

I know that in Corda, initiating flows can invoke subflows to speak to other parties or automate common tasks.

Can an acceptor/initiated flow do the same?

In particular, suppose `A` initiates a flow with `B`. Can `B`, as part of the acceptor/initiated flow, invoke a subflow that speaks to `C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are no constraints on invoking subflows in acceptor/initiated flows, regardless of whom they speak to.